# Facebook API: AppID|AppSecret token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JS to fetch a page feed using the facebook graph API, but in order to fetch the page's feed I need an access token. My current access token is set to expire in an hour, but I can use `AppID|AppSecret` as a permanent access token.

My question is: Since viewing the page source will show the acess token, is using the appID|appSecret combination a safe approach to having a permanent access_token?

```js
var facebookFeed = [];
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '173668203065748',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });
    FB.api(
        '/officialstackoverflow/feed',
        'GET', {
            "access_token": "EAACEdEose0cBACP92ZBJexyw6OhDqs7SbBIme4CSisaI4UDgbJHDOa0NVjoXOXSJB7SD6549CB6M3KAdV11ySAn6wlJAMI4YEFEdfw2cM9JpovUG4NZC3VsCWcajbXfXWSWMmQQDR1fM9bzk6YPxMUYOiqBQnWrEm0IzbaCQZDZD",
            "fields": "full_picture,message,created_time,type,link,id"
        },
        function (response) {
            writePosts(response.data);
        }
    );
};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function writePosts(facebookFeed) {
    for (i = 0; i < facebookFeed.length; i++) {
        var currentPost = facebookFeed[i];
        var myDate = new Date(currentPost.created_time);
        if (currentPost.type == "photo" || currentPost.type == "status") {
        if(!currentPost.link)currentPost.link="http://facebook.com//"+currentPost.id;
            console.log(currentPost);
                   }
    }
}
```

```css
.facebookText {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.facebookImage {
 width: 100%;
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}

.facebookPost {
 width: 400px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px 5px 3px 5px;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.facebookPost:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.facebookTime {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: italic;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: see my answer. btw, you should NEVER post an access token on stackoverflow. it is still a valid one for 12 minutes, and i can access your pages with it. you should immediately change your app secret.

Comment: well you can do that even with this generated access_token?

Comment: of course, why wouldn´t i? btw, editing the question does not help, it´s already in the history. tokens are ALWAYS meant to be kept secret.

Comment: the access token has no permissions, I only need to read the newsfeed of a public page that I am not an admin of. How could that access_token grant any permissions?

Comment: it had the "manage_pages" permission. either way, you should never post any access token anywhere. access tokens are like house keys, you don´t just let other people copy them, right? ;)

Comment: I see your point, thanks. I'm marking your answer as the response but can you think of any safe way for me to browse the page's feed using client side code?

Comment: you would need to authorize every single user for that. so no, there is no safe way. and again, you should implement caching, or you will api limits with a lot of users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122681/discussion-between-paul-ghiran-and-luschn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "App Secret" for a reason, you should not expose it on the client. You should not expose any Token to other users anyway. You need to do that server side, and you should implement some caching - just in case you get many users and hit an API limit.